# manually register a template expression to watch for change detection

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I receive an array from the user, and pass it whole to a third party library. Since there is no expression based on the values of the array, any deep changes in the array do not register for change detection, even with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default`

Specifically,

```
<agm-polygon [paths]="paths"></agm-polygon>
```

```js
function onUpdate(el){
 this.paths.push(el);
}
```

will not work. The reason is that during change detection, only registered template expressions are checked against their previous value, and while `paths` is registered, `paths`'s properties are not (and angular's change detection is shallow).

I think I need to register the array's properties as template expressions, but don't know how.

P.S. Manually triggering CD is not going to work. CD is being run, it just ignores the properties

Answer (score 0):

Create a new instance of the array:

```js
function onUpdate(el){
  this.paths = [...this.paths, el];
}
```

This will create a new reference for the child component, so its `onChange` will be called, so it can react to the changes. Hopefully it has some mechanism not to re-render everything, but only the new or changed things.

Comment: yes, I can do that, but am looking to avoid that. My code is a library, and this will force all users to constantly create new instances. It's also not performative, since arrays can be quite large and two dimensional.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the array is 2-dimensional, the `...`operator creates a shallow copy, doesn't touch the actual items in the top level array.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to implement the `DoCheck` interface, and then do your custom/deep change detection in `ngDoCheck`.

```
ngDoCheck() {
 const oldArr = this.oldArr,
       newarr = this.arr;
 ... array comparison logic
}
```